# Insert function not working

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, debugging, insert

```
ClearAll[y, x, S]
S = List[];
For[i = 1; x = 0, i < 100, i++, x = i/100;
 h = FindRoot[
   Log[((-2*x*y - I*a*x)/(2 (1 - x^2)) + 
      Sqrt[(2*x*y + I*a*x)^2/(4 (1 - x^2)^2) - (
        y^2 + I*a*y)/(1 - x^2)])/((-2*x*y - I*a*x)/(2 (1 - x^2)) - 
      Sqrt[(2*x*y + I*a*x)^2/(4 (1 - x^2)^2) - (
        y^2 + I*a*y)/(1 - x^2)])] == 
    2*I*Sqrt[(2*x*y + I*a*x)^2/(4 (1 - x^2)^2) - (
       y^2 + I*a*y)/(1 - x^2)], {y, 0}];
 \[Gamma] = Im[y /. h];
 (*Print[\[Gamma],x];*);
 Insert[S, i, -1];]
S
```

This code gives an empty list and I don't understand why the Insert function is not working! Can someone help?

Comment: The Insert function returns a new list with the new element inserted but does not modify its arguments in place. You have to assign the output of Insert to `S` in order to modify `S` at each step. Otherwise look at e.g. `AppendTo`, but that may come with a performance penalty. In general, For loops are not very idiomatic in Mathematica; alternatives are `Table` or mapping functions over lists.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!